# Bad: [jquery] function with wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm new to the world of programming, I would have a problem to ask you. I hope you can help me.
I have a problem on a wordpress website. I use a theme that creates a menu for the "mobile" version that uses the following function to open the menu.

```js
container.find( '.dropdown-toggle' ).click(
    function( e ) {
        var _this = $( this );
        e.preventDefault();
        _this.toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
        _this.next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
        _this.attr( 'aria-expanded', _this.attr( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false' );
        _this.html( _this.html() === screenReaderText.expand ? screenReaderText.collapse : screenReaderText.expand );
    });
```

of course everything works great when one clicks on the object with class `.dropdown-toggle`.

now I would like to apply that functionality to the writing of every single element. Let me explain better to create submenus in wordpress I use (href = #), this causes the submenu to be created but when I click on the link the submenu does not open. The theme uses a small arrow to open the submenu. I would like the user to click on the href = # link to open the relevant submenu.The html for the menu is of the type:

```js
<ul>
    <li id="menu-item-2476" class="menu-item" aria-haspopup="true">
        <a href="#">menu 1</a>
        <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false"></button>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-435" class="menu-item">
                <a href="https://www.myhost.it">sub menu1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

once I click the `.dropdown-toggle` element the html becomes

```js
<ul>
    <li id="menu-item-2476" class="menu-item" aria-haspopup="true">
        <a href="#">menu 1</a>
        <button class="dropdown-toggle toggled-on" aria-expanded="true"></button>
        <ul class="sub-menu toggled-on">
            <li id="menu-item-435" class="menu-item">
                <a href="https://www.myhost.it">sub menu1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to create a new function by copying the previous one but I can't make it work, I replace the `.dropdwon-toggle` with "#" but nothing when I click on the link # it doesn't open and the document doesn't replace the css classes like the function original of the theme. Is someone so good that you can help me create this little function?
if you need to see the js of the theme this is the link [LINK](https://www.pilloledolanda.it/wp-content/themes/islemag/js/script.all.js).

thanks in advance for any help.

** ### UPDATE ### **

thanks for the answer "***stackingjasoncooper***" and to "***Hoang Tran Son***" for editing the post, indeed sorry but it was my first post in this community and above all I translate from Google ITA> ENG.
I tried the change but unfortunately it doesn't work, or rather it puts the "`.toggled-on`" class in the "`a`" tag instead of the "`<ul class="sub-menu>`" tag, moreover once you click on the "`a`" link the writing inside disappears, also inserts the field `aria-expanded="false"`, which should belong to "button". I lost it all afternoon but to no avail, indeed sorry for my ignorance. This is html after clicking on the menu text

```
    <ul><li id="menu-item-2476" class="menu-item" aria-haspopup="true">
        <a href="#" class="toggled-on" aria-expanded="false"></a>
          <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false"></button>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-435" class="menu-item">
                    <a href="https://www.myhost.it">sub menu1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
```

In the first message I have not inserted all the script, maybe there is some problem in the code before the script inserted in the first post.

```
function( $ ) {
            var body = $( 'body' ), _window = $( window ),  nav, button, menu;

            button = $( '.menu-toggle' );
            menu   = $( '.nav-menu' );

            function initMainNavigation( container ) {

                // Add dropdown toggle that display child menu items.
                container.find( '.menu-item-has-children > a' ).after( '<button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">' + screenReaderText.expand + '</button>' );
                container.find( '.page_item_has_children > a' ).after( '<button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">' + screenReaderText.expand + '</button>' );

                // Toggle buttons and submenu items with active children menu items.
                container.find( '.current-menu-ancestor > button' ).addClass( 'toggled-on' );
                container.find( '.current-menu-ancestor > .sub-menu' ).addClass( 'toggled-on' );

                // Add menu items with submenus to aria-haspopup="true".
                container.find( '.menu-item-has-children' ).attr( 'aria-haspopup', 'true' );

                /* container.find( '.dropdown-toggle' ).click( */
                container.find( '.dropdown-toggle, ul:not(.sub-menu) > .menu-item a' ).click(
                    function( e ) {
                        var _this = $( this );
                        e.preventDefault();
                        _this.toggleClass( 'toggled-on, ' );
                        _this.next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
                        _this.attr( 'aria-expanded', _this.attr( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false' );
                        _this.html( _this.html() === screenReaderText.expand ? screenReaderText.collapse : screenReaderText.expand );
                    }
                );
            }
```

I'm looking for some jquery guide and I understand (***I hope***) that the "`.next`" function returns the next neighbor tag. So if I run in the "`<button>`" field the next field is "`<ul>`" (*the submenu*). `ul` is in fact the field that must receive the "`.toggled-on`" class to be open. If what I understand is right .... I should create a new function that includes only the "`a`" field but with two times (`.next`), this is because the "submenu" field is two html tags after. I also tried to insert (`.next.next`) but nothing!

Thanks again for any response.

### **- MY RESOLUTION**

Good morning, thank you all from the community. I managed to make it work as I wanted. I had to insert a new script, using `.next()` correctly or at least I hope. Once the script was implemented I realized that if I clicked the `href="#"` the browser brought the screen up, I entered a condition and it seems that it works.
Thanks again to the whole community!

```
        container.find( '.menu-item a' ).click(
            function( e ) {
                var _this = $( this );
                e.preventDefault();
                _this.next().next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
                _this.next( '.dropdown-toggle' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
                _this.next().attr( 'aria-expanded', _this.next().attr( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false' );
                if ( _this.attr('href') == "#" ) {}
                else{
                   window.location.href = this; 
                }
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to recreate that function if you can edit it. You could expand the [jQuery selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) in the [click listener](https://api.jquery.com/click/) in your function:

```
container.find( '.dropdown-toggle, .menu-item a' ).click(...
```

Basically that line is saying:

1. Go to the 'container' (a jQuery element defined elsewhere)
2. Find inside the container things have the class `dropdown-toggle` or `a` tags inside of things with the `menu-item` class
3. Add a click listener to those things so that when they are clicked, the following happens...

Though the `.menu-item a` selector might be too broad, and include `sub-menu a` tags and break them (that `e.preventDefault()` will stop the links from working). So we should use the [jQuery not selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to be more specific:

```
container.find( '.dropdown-toggle, ul:not(.sub-menu) > .menu-item a' ).click(...
```

`a` tags inside of things with `menu-item` class that are directly inside of a `ul` that does NOT have the `sub-menu` class

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I wrote some news in the post.
Thanks again for taking the time to help me!

Comment: Hi, I was able to solve my problems. I created a new function, I edited the post to insert the resolution, so anyone with my problem can see how to do it. Hoping I didn't write bad code. Thank you!